# Flexbox align item vertical 1/3

Tags: css, flexbox

Now I learned how to vertical centering an item with flexbox, but how can I align the item to the 1/3 position vertically? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean the space below the flex item to be 3 times the space above, you can add pseudo-elements with `flex-grow` 1 and 3:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  background: #aaf;
}
#container > div {
  height: 50px;
  background: #afa;
}
#container::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
#container::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is better because when the content is large and fills the entire parent block, it remains inside the parent block and does not go beyond the boundaries of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform: translate`

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 180px;
  background: gray;
}
#container > div {
  position: relative;
  top: 33%;
  transform: translateY(-33%);
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```